# How do I draw a 3D arrow in R?

Tags: r, graphics, vector, 3d

I am using the rgl package to create 3D plots of my data. For some reasons (3D PCA biplots) I need vectors -- a line segment with an arrow. And I'm stuck, because I want to have 3D cones as arrow heads.

Somehow, I cannot wrap my senile mind around the geometry of the problem. Say, I would draw the vector with

```
segments3d( rbind( c( 0, 0, 0 ), c( 3, 3, 3 ) ) )
```

that is, a vector from the origin of the user coordinate system to [3,3,3].

I would like to create a cone with the tip at [3,3,3]. The base of the cone can be formed with a circle. Drawing a circle on the xz plane (perpendicular to the y plane) with radius r is easy:

```
n <- 10
sin.t <- sin( seq( 0, 2 * pi, len= n ) )
cos.t <- cos( seq( 0, 2 * pi, len= n ) )
r <- 0.1 
xv <- x + r * sin.t
yv <- rep( y, n )
zv <- z + r * cos.t
```

but how do I now transform these points such that the circle is now perpendicular to the vector? And its center 0.2 from the tip along the vectors direction? Once I have this transformation, I will draw triangles with the `triangles3d` function, each triangle having one corner at the tip and two vertices within the points of the circle.

This is basic maths, and I know the 18 year old me would not have a problem (or even a 28 year old me). Any hook (as opposed to fish) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the demos for rgl there is a cone3d function. It takes the base and the tip seperaately. In any event you could do something like this:

```
vec=rbind( c( 0, 0, 0 ), c( 3, 3, 3 ) )
segments3d( vec )


cone3d(base=vec[2,]-(vec[1,]+vec[2,]/6), 
     #this makes the head go 1/6th the length of the arrow
       rad=0.5,
       tip=vec[2,],
       col="blue",
       front="lines",
       back="lines")
```

Here is the cone3d function:

```
   cone3d <- function(base=c(0,0,0),tip=c(0,0,1),rad=1,n=30,draw.base=TRUE,qmesh=FALSE,
                    trans = par3d("userMatrix"), ...) {
   ax <- tip-base
   if (missing(trans) && !rgl.cur()) trans <- diag(4)
   ### is there a better way?
   if (ax[1]!=0) {
     p1 <- c(-ax[2]/ax[1],1,0)
     p1 <- p1/sqrt(sum(p1^2))
     if (p1[1]!=0) {
       p2 <- c(-p1[2]/p1[1],1,0)
       p2[3] <- -sum(p2*ax)
       p2 <- p2/sqrt(sum(p2^2))
     } else {
       p2 <- c(0,0,1)
     }
   } else if (ax[2]!=0) {
     p1 <- c(0,-ax[3]/ax[2],1)
     p1 <- p1/sqrt(sum(p1^2))
     if (p1[1]!=0) {
       p2 <- c(0,-p1[3]/p1[2],1)
       p2[3] <- -sum(p2*ax)
       p2 <- p2/sqrt(sum(p2^2))
     } else {
       p2 <- c(1,0,0)
     }
   } else {
     p1 <- c(0,1,0); p2 <- c(1,0,0)
   }
   degvec <- seq(0,2*pi,length=n+1)[-1]
   ecoord2 <- function(theta) {
     base+rad*(cos(theta)*p1+sin(theta)*p2)
   }
   i <- rbind(1:n,c(2:n,1),rep(n+1,n))
   v <- cbind(sapply(degvec,ecoord2),tip)
   if (qmesh) 
     ## minor kluge for quads -- draw tip twice
     i <- rbind(i,rep(n+1,n))
   if (draw.base) {
     v <- cbind(v,base)
     i.x <- rbind(c(2:n,1),1:n,rep(n+2,n))
     if (qmesh)  ## add base twice
       i.x <-  rbind(i.x,rep(n+2,n))
     i <- cbind(i,i.x)
   }
   if (qmesh) v <- rbind(v,rep(1,ncol(v))) ## homogeneous
   if (!qmesh)
     triangles3d(v[1,i],v[2,i],v[3,i],...)
   else
     return(rotate3d(qmesh3d(v,i,material=...), matrix=trans))
 }
```