# 3d Vector plotting and visualization in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

Anyone know of any packages in R that can plot 3D vectors? I would like to plot some vectors over a 3 dimensional data set. I know scatterplot3d *looks* like it should be able to do the job, but I didn't see any documentation for vectors specifically (I would like to be able to change the origin of vectors as well).

Comment: Do you have to do it in R? There are better tools for visualisation of vector fields. Like Kitware Paraview for example.

Comment: All of my data is in R objects and it would be very cumbersome to make the conversion just for visualization.

Answer (score 4):

[rgl](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/index.html) is a great package for 3d plotting. It is very like 2d plotting except that you use `plot3d` instead of `plot`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165899/how-do-i-draw-a-3d-arrow-in-r) on SO suggests a way to draw arrows in rgl.