# How to plot 3D direction and speed using R or MATLAB?

Tags: r, matlab, plot, 3d, direction

I am looking for a way to plot a wind 3D direction in R or MATLAB.

There are 3 given vector components:

- `u` : x-axis (horizontal)
- `v` : y-axis (horizontal)
- `w` : z-axis (vertical)

For plotting wind directions in 2D, there is the traditional way of using a rose plot like this: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Wind_rose_plot.jpg

Do you have any idea, how I can plot this in 3D using the R statistic engine or MATLAB, by using the additional `w` vector?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: For R, this might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20692992/1191259

Answer (score 3):

In MATLAB `quiver3` will be the most relevant to your case. More information and examples [here.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quiver3.html)